# Sorting table data from mysql php on icons click

Tags: php, mysql, html, sorting, html-table

I am going to make a table in html. I want to fetch the data from database(mysql) and show it in the same table using php. But the problem against me is that I didn't make this kind of work before. I want to give arrow icon on the table columns to depict sorting columns(ascending and descending). Also the icons should be changed(up and down) when they are pressed and values should be changed/sort in php/mysql.

In it how can I put the code so the php query is called to sort the data from mysql when the sorting icons is pressed. I want to learn the process completely. Please help I don't know anything about this.

Hope this is easier for the experienced PHP programmers.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Break down the required functionality in small tasks and try to complete those. There are many resources available on the internet for learning. Please don't expect some ready made code from here.

Comment: I want to show the data in a html table which is retrieved from the Mysql table. In that (data showing) html table's per column I want to give clickable button for sorting. So after clicking the data should be get sorted.